# Add Class in CSS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, bundle

Example Normal Stylesheet :

```
<link class="ks-sidebar-dark-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/styles/themes/sidebar-black.min.css">
```

How to put `class="ks-sidebar-dark-style"` in StyleBundle `BundleConfig.cs` ?

Current config :

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
          "~/assets/styles/themes/sidebar-black.min.css"));
```

Answer (score 0):

BundleConfig is nothing more than bundle configuration moved to separate file. It used to be part of app startup code (filters, bundles, routes used to be configured in one class)

To add this file, first you need to add the Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization nuget package to your web project:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
```

Just create another BundleConfig.cs file under App_Start
Mine looks like this :

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace CodeRepository.Web
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

Then modify global.asax to look like this :

```
using System.Web.Optimization;

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

Comment: How I can make a class in link stylesheet like in the example